# Is it possible to implement this generic flip?

Tags: haskell, monads, reader-monad

I would like to write an object with the type signature:

```
genericFlip ::
  ( MonadReader (o (n c)) m
  , MonadReader a n
  , MonadReader b o
  )
    => m (n (o c))
```

That is essentially a flip for monad readers.

Now it is easy enough to write the version of this that looks like:

```
genericFlip ::
  ( MonadReader (b -> a -> c) m
  , MonadReader a n
  , MonadReader b o
  )
    => m (n (o c))
  genericFlip = do
    f <- ask
    return $ do
      a <- ask
      return $ do
        b <- ask
        return $ f b a
```

Or even substitute `(->)` for `Reader`, but no matter how I wrack my brain I can't seem to make a definition that works for all readers.

Is it possible to make a total object that has this type signature in Haskell?

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, I suggest not generalising `m` to `MonadReader`. In the type of `flip`...

```
flip :: (a -> b -> c) -> (b -> a -> c)
```

... the middle arrow is not like the others: it merely links the input and the output of the flip. Adopting that simplification, we end up with a simpler type for the `genericFlip` you propose:

```
genericFlip :: (MonadReader a n, MonadReader b o) => o (n c) -> n (o c)
```

In any case, `genericFlip` can't be implemented with this signature. On its own, the `MonadReader` interface doesn't provide a way to supply an environment to a computation, which would be necessary for swapping the layers. Consider, for instance, the specialised `genericFlip` from your question:

```
genericFlip' :: (MonadReader a n, MonadReader b o) => (b -> a -> c) -> n (o c)
genericFlip' f = do
  a <- ask
  return $ do
    b <- ask
    return $ f b a
```

It fundamentally relies on `f` being a function, which means we can supply environments to it (and, as you note, were we using `Reader` instead we could do the same thing through `runReader`). Ultimately, all `MonadReader` does here is turning functions into reader computations, as made transparent by this pointfree spelling:

```
genericFlip' :: (MonadReader a n, MonadReader b o) => (b -> a -> c) -> n (o c)
genericFlip' = fmap reader . reader . flip
```

One generalisation of `flip` we do have is [`distribute`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/distributive-0.6.1/docs/Data-Distributive.html):

```
distribute :: (Distributive g, Functor f) => f (g a) -> g (f a)
```

`distribute @((->) _)` is also known as [`flap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/relude-0.6.0.0/docs/Relude-Functor-Fmap.html#v:flap) or [`(??)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.19/docs/Control-Lens-Lens.html#v:-63--63-), while `distribute @((->) _) @((->) _)` is `flip` itself.

`Distributive`, though, doesn't quite untie us from functions in the way we might hope in the context of this question. Every distributive functor is isomorphic to `(->) r` for some specific `r`. The connections become more evident when we look at the `Representable` class, which is in principle equivalent to `Distributive`, but uses a more sophisticated encoding that makes the isomorphism explicit. In addition to `distribute` being a generalisation of `flip`, we have `index` as a function application analogue, and `tabulate`, which looks a lot like `reader`. The class, in fact, offers [a default `MonadReader` implementation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/adjunctions-4.4/docs/Data-Functor-Rep.html#g:10), which can be conveniently derived via [the `Co` newtype](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/adjunctions-4.4/docs/Data-Functor-Rep.html#t:Co).

On a final note, something that, in spite of not exactly fitting our proposed generalised flip signatures, is very much flippable is `ReaderT r (ReaderT s m) a`, which boils down to `r -> s -> m a`. That is arguably not all that useful, though, as in practice one typically would, rather than having nested reader layes, combine the environments into a single type and have just one reader layer (see also [the `RIO` monad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/rio-0.1.13.0/docs/RIO.html)).

Answer (score 0):

No. It's not possible.

There's nothing about the first signature that makes o traversable.

Comment: "There's nothing about the first signature that makes `o` traversable" -- Or `n` distributive.

Answer (score 0):

Simply by relying on `MonadReader` you can't, but with `Traversable` you can get this:

```hs
genericFlip :: (Traversable o, MonadReader (o (n c)) m, Monad n) => m (n (o c))
genericFlip = do
  onc <- ask
  return $ sequence onc
```

Adding other `MonadReader` constraints will not do any harm, but I can't see exactly what you are trying to achieve with those monads or their environments.

```hs
genericFlip ::
  (Traversable o, MonadReader (o (n c)) m, MonadReader a n, MonadReader b o) => m (n (o c))
genericFlip = asks sequence
```

An example could possibly help.

Comment: If we're going down this route, it could be useful to ask for `Distributive` instead of `Traversable` -- function-like things tend to be the former rather than the latter.